# Facebook-PHP-SDK: api('/me') not working, very strange

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Here is my code:

```
    $session = $facebook->getSession();
var_dump($session);/*it says session is perfectly established*/
try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    echo '<br>';
    var_dump($uid);/*User id is found*/
    $fb_user = $me = $facebook->api('/me');/*PHP execution doesn't go forward, here it breaks*/
    echo '<br>';
    var_dump($fb_user);/*PHP execution doesn't come up to here*/
```

**EDITED:**
I have print_r the $exception in the catch section and got the following long message:

```
FacebookApiException Object
(
    [result:protected] => Array
        (
            [error_code] => 6
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [message] => name lookup timed out
                    [type] => CurlException
                )

        )

    [message:protected] => name lookup timed out
    [string:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 6
    [file:protected] => /home/abusadat/public_html/.../facebook.php
    [line:protected] => 614
    [trace:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/abusadat/public_html/.../facebook.php
                    [line] => 575
                    [function] => makeRequest
                    [class] => Facebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/me
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [method] => GET
                                    [access_token] => ******...******
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/abusadat/public_html/.../facebook.php
                    [line] => 539
                    [function] => _oauthRequest
                    [class] => Facebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/me
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [method] => GET
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/abusadat/public_html/.../facebook.php
                    [line] => 492
                    [function] => _graph
                    [class] => Facebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /me
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/abusadat/public_html/.../fb-connect.php
                    [line] => 31
                    [function] => api
                    [class] => Facebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Facebook Object
                                        (
                                            [appId:protected] => ******...******
                                            [session:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [access_token] => ******...******
                                                    [base_domain] => abusadat.com
                                                    [expires] => 1312567200
                                                    [secret] => ******...******
                                                    [session_key] => ******...******
                                                    [sig] => ******...******
                                                    [uid] => ******...******
                                                )

                                            [signedRequest:protected] => 
                                            [sessionLoaded:protected] => 1
                                            [cookieSupport:protected] => 1
                                            [baseDomain:protected] => 
                                            [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => _graph
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => /me
                                )

                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/abusadat/public_html/.../index.php
                    [line] => 29
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /home/abusadat/public_html/.../fb-connect.php
                        )

                    [function] => include_once
                )

        )

)
```

I am using SDK version 2.1.2. I have some restriction to use SDK 3 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that an exception is being thrown and that you don't see it because your PHP error reporting settings are not tuned properly.

Add this to the top of your PHP file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You should then see a PHP error when visiting the page.

Comment: Can you show us the complete code? You have a try claue, but you don't show the catch clause. What are you doing if an exception is being thrown?

Comment: you are right. I have print_r the $exception and got error message. Please look at the edited section of the question for that error message